# Using UrlFetchApp in Google Apps Script to fetch Google Meet

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am using URLFetchApp to fetch a Google Meet using the Meet URL. Google Meet will not load through iFrame or object/embed and Google Meet will only load on the Chrome/Chromium based browsers.

```
function getHTML(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

This works along with using innerHTML to set the html contents of a div. However, I am getting the error message that "Meet doesn't work on your browser" even though I am using Chrome. Is there a way to inform the URL you are fetching that a specific browser will be used?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do when you "fetch a Google Meet"? What is the exact url you are using and what is your intention?

Comment: Each Google Meet has a unique URL. I want to embed the Google Meet window into a div. Normally, you would use something like iFrame to do that but Google Meets will not load in an iFrame - you'll receive a "cannot connect" generic error. URLFetchApp will retrieve it but for some reason Google Meet thinks it's not a Chrome browser.

Comment: I assume you want to embed the link in your Website - so how do you return `response.getContentText();` to the clientside? Are you using an Apps Script Web App?

Comment: Yes, URLFetchApp is a GAS serverside that returns the HTML content back to the client.

Comment: Without you providing the full code it is hard to understand how you want to open the url clientside and why you cannot just implement into your JS code `window.open(url);`

Comment: As stated above, I want to open the URL in a DIV in much the same way you would open something in an iFrame. Google Meets cannot be opened in an iFrame. They fail on load. This is the reason I thought I could use URLFetchApp in GAS to fetch the Meet and then pass it along to the div (the code above...) The problem I have encountered with URLFetchApp is that Google Meet thinks it's a non Chrome browser. My original question, also stated above, is there a way to pass along a browser target using URLFetchApp.